# 32 and 64 bit MSSQL on same server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to install a 32bit instance of SQL Server and a 64bit instance on the same 64-bit server?

I have ODBC drivers that are 32bit, and need to use these as linked servers in SQL Server, so I need to install the 32bit version.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done that, but logically it's possible.

As 32bit software could work easily on 64bit OS.

So, for this, you need 64 bit OS, and you can install two instances of 32 bit and 64 bit mssql server.

TO run both, you just need to change the port on which sql server will listen, and it should work flawlessly.

Once again, I haven't tried it but I am sure it should be possible.

Thanx

Comment: I have done this, and can verify that it is possible.

Comment: Thanx for confirming. Request you to please accept this as an answer.

Comment: Not my question, so I can't accept... you might want to direct that request at @Lock instead.

Comment: Oh thanx. Never checked this.